# Do not allow decimal numbers in textfield on form submittion in CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have a textfield in HTML form. On form submition i want to prompt the user if a decimal number is entered. How can i do it using a regular expression in cofeescript?

```
jQuery('form#adjustment_invoice_form input[type=submit]').live 'click', ->
  if !(/[^0-9]/.test(adj_value))
    alert("Decimal numbers are not allowed for")
    false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not allow the decimal `.` character:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(".no_decimal").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 190)
      return false;
  });
});
```

The above in CoffeeScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready ->
  jQuery('.no_decimal').keydown (e) ->
    if e.keyCode == 190
      return false
    return
  return
```

---

If you still insist on checking only on Form Submission, use this:

```
if adj_value.indexOf('.') != -1
  alert("Decimal numbers are not allowed for")
  return false
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. I want to check it on form submission not on keydown